# Error while replacing '?' with mean value in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a car dataset where I want to replace the '?' values in the column normalized-values to the mean of the remaining numerical values. The code I have used is:

```
mean = df["normalized-losses"].mean()
df["normalized-losses"].replace("?",mean)
```

However, this produces the error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '???164164?158?158?192192188188??121988111811811814814814814811014513713710110110111078106106858585107????145??104104104113113150150150150129115129115?115118?93939393?142???161161161161153153???125125125137128128128122103128128122103168106106128108108194194231161161??161161??16116116111911915415415474?186??????1501041501041501048383831021021021021028989858587877477819191919191919191168168168168134134134134134134656565656519719790?1221229494949494?256???1037410374103749595959595'

Can anyone help with the way in which I can convert the '?' values to the mean values. Also, this is the first time I am working with the Pandas package so if I have made any silly mistakes, please forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for convert non numeric values to `NaN`s and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `mean`:

```
vals = pd.to_numeric(df["normalized-losses"], errors='coerce')
df["normalized-losses"] = vals.fillna(vals.mean()) 
#data from jpp
print (df)
   normalized-losses
0                1.0
1                2.0
2                3.0
3                3.4
4                5.0
5                6.0
6                3.4
```

**Details**:

```
print (vals)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    5.0
5    6.0
6    NaN
Name: normalized-losses, dtype: float64

print (vals.mean())
3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` followed by`fillna()`:

```
df['normalized-losses'] = df['normalized-losses'].replace('?',np.NaN)
df['normalized-losses'].fillna(df['normalized-losses'].mean())
```

Answer (score 1):

The mean of a series of mixed types is not defined. Convert to numeric and *then* use `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, '?', 5, 6, '??']})

mean = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').mean()
df['B'] = df['A'].replace('?', mean)

print(df)

    A    B
0   1    1
1   2    2
2   3    3
3   ?  3.4
4   5    5
5   6    6
6  ??   ??
```

If you need to replace *all* non-numeric values, then use `fillna`:

```
nums = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
df['B'] = nums.fillna(nums.mean())

print(df)

    A    B
0   1  1.0
1   2  2.0
2   3  3.0
3   ?  3.4
4   5  5.0
5   6  6.0
6  ??  3.4
```